# How to clear contents of ObjectContext in Entity Framework 1.0

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext

Is there a method of manually clearing/resetting an ObjectContext back to its initial state? Note that I can't just instantiate a new context.

This is using the 1.0 version of the Entity Framework.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't instantiate a new context, why do you want to reset the one you have? Wouldn't 'resetting' it be the same thing?

Comment: Because the lifetime of the context is set per-thread and it is referenced in several places. The calling code accepts it as a parameter and doesn't know how to instantiate a new instance. In this specific case, I'm trying to debug a problem and I want to clear the context without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

ObjectContext is meant to be a short-lived object, it shouldn't be cached like that. Normal usage should look like:

```
using(var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    // Select/update/insert/delete
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of how it should be used and in my case it is fairly short-lived. Each context exists for the duration of handling one message sent via NServiceBus. A new context is started with each event handler. In this case though, I'm running into an issue where objects don't seem to be detaching correctly and I want to reset the context to see if that fixes things.

Comment: Well because that's the way it should be used, I don't think there's a way to reset it to the initial state.

Comment: Why should the object context be short lived? Doesn't the fact that it track object state mean that it should last as long as objects need to be tracked? e.g. for as long, say, as a Win Form exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the [Detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738697(v=VS.90).aspx) method for each entity that was loaded to the context.