# How do I clear object context

Tags: entity-framework

If I ran several queries and ObjectContext was populated with entities how do I clear the context if I don't need those entities anymore. I know that I need to dispose the context as soon as possible, but in this case it is not possible. So is there any way that I can remove those objects from the context?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774395/how-to-clear-contents-of-objectcontext-in-entity-framework-1-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [Detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738697(v=VS.90).aspx) each entity in the context.

Comment: I thought about it at first, but I was hoping there's a better way. I guess there's not.

Answer (score 11):

There is no method for "clearing" ObjectContext. The only way to do that is to Dispose current instance of ObjectContext and start the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Detach each entity in the context.

Max is right, but when you want to do anything that take a long time, the context stores many objects and keeps growing up in memory, and making your app be slow.

It's call by leak memory.

I have this problem with the EntityFramework 6 now, but I don't know how "exactly" to fix It.

Always that I need to do a query, I get up the context and do It, but this action is differ, I have many things to calculate, in a loop, and I keep the context until finish. For now I am disposing my list after flush, but I still have leak memory  in my system, and the context with sure has this problem. Any suggest "team" ? I don't know the entity framework works.

Comment: This doesn't seem an answer to the question, it doesn't address the problem. Better write this as a comment

Comment: I Tried, believe me, but my reputation is low. Sorry !

Comment: If you find that your Context is growing and growing as you load more entities into it... and you do NOT need to save any changes on those entities (maybe you are just loading them to read values or use them in other computations, but you are not making changes to them that you need to save back to the database), well, you can use the AsNoTracking() method on the query to tell EF do not track them, and it will save a ton of memory. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203.aspx

Comment: GREAT bro, you're right! I had to think better my database organization to resolve some problems with performance and memory.